# Bulk insert in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I insert large amount of records like 20K using bulk insert,it will be working fine when I insert only one entity. But when I used to insert multiple entities like one to many it will be inserting only the parent entity the child entities are not inserted.

My Entities and Code

```
Customer.cs
    public class Customer
     {
        public Customer()
        {
           this.AccountCustomers = new HashSet<AccountCustomer>();
        }
        public int CustomerId{get;set;}
        public int CustomerName{get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<AccountCustomer> AccountCustomers { get; set; }
     }

 AccountCustomer.cs
     public partial class AccountCustomer
      {
       public int CustomerId { get; set; }        
       public string CustomData { get; set; }
       public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }       

       public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
      }

My code:
  List<Customer> customerList = CreateCustomer();
  for (int index = 0; index < 20000;index++ )
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.CustomerName= "Parthi";
            AccountCustomer accountCustomer = new AccountCustomer();
            accountCustomer.CustomdData= "customdata";
            accountCustomer.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            customer.AccountCustomers.Add(accountCustomer);
            customerList.Add(customer);
        }

      private static void AddCustomer(List<Customer> customerList)
      {
        using (var ctx =new Directdialogs())
        {
            using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    ctx.BulkInsert(customerList);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                    transactionScope.Complete();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    transactionScope.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my code but it will inserted only the customer entity data not insert the account customer data, Is bulk insert not supporting to insert multiple entities anybody knows help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `BulkInsert` is an extension method.

Comment: What is `BulkInsert`? Not something in EF

Comment: It is in Entity framework 6 friend.

Comment: [It is not part of DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx), Are you sure you don't have [this nuget package](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) installed?

Comment: Ya sure it is not a part of DbContext, after  I installed this "Install-Package EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6" in nuget package.

Comment: That is not EF6, that is a 3rd party package.

Comment: Strange to do the bulkinsert and savechanges. Savechanges would save the data to the database too.

Answer (score 6):

The [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) project you are using (`BulkInsert` comes from this 3rd party project not EF6) only supports bulk inserting to one table at a time.

If you want the project to be able to insert in to multiple tables at a time to be able to handle child entities you will need to modify the code to do it yourself (If you do write it yourself please share and contribute the code back to the project).

**EDIT:** However, this may be a lot harder than you think at first glance. You will have no way to know what columns with Identity values (be it a `int` identity or a `uniqueidentifier`) where set to during the bulk insert operation reliably, so setting up Foreign Key relationships may be very hard to do. You may need to pre-set any identity values before you insert.